# Container view size not changing when the embedded controller's view height constraint changes

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I have a container view that embeds another view controller in `viewDidLoad`. When I hide the embedded view controller's view, the container view persists on the screen. The embedded controller's view has a `Greater or Equal` height constraint which I set to 0 when I hide the view.

How do I make the container view hide when I hide the embedded controller's view?

EDIT:

I realized that my question is misleading.. I am setting the height constraint of the embedded controller's view to 0 and I am expecting its container height to decrease to 0. Is that a wrong assumption?

It works if I set the height constraint's relation to `Equal`, it stops working if I change the relation to `Greater Than or Equal`.

Embedded controller's view hierarchy
[image: Embedded controller's view hierarchy]

Here's what the view controller with the container view looks like -

[image: View controller with the container view]

I want to be able to change the height constraint of the view embedded inside container view and cause the container view to match the new height (0 or 44, depending of whether I want to show the view to the user. I make that decision in `viewWillAppear` inside the embedded controller's `.swift` file).

This is what I want to see when I set the height constraint to 0 -

[image: Goal]

The reason why I want to use the `Greater Than or Equal` relation for height constraint is due to accessibility. I want the embedded view to grow in size when the user increases the font size.

Comment: Actually, it is normal that superview (container, parent) do not hide when some its subview (embedded, child) was set to be hidden.

Comment: If you want to hide parent you can call self.superview.hidden = YES;

Comment: @nambatee what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Vyacheslav edited the original question

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing your code so its difficult to see whats going wrong.  In general there are a few ways to hide your container view:

1. Give it a degenerate height constraint.  It looks like you are doing this.  Are you calling **layoutIfNeeded** to force recalcualtion of the frame?
2. set the container's **isHidden** property to true
3. set the container's **backgroundColor** to .clear

number 3 is the easiest.